# Creating a nested dictionary using two lists with different number of keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Keys = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
values = ['a','a1','a2','b','b4','b5','c','c4','c3','d','d4','d6','e','e4','e3']



output = {'a':{'a':['a1','a2'],'b':['b4','b5'],'c':['c4','c3'],'d':['d4','d6'],'e':['e4','e3']}}
```

- I have two lists, **keys** and **Values**.
- **"Keys"** contains the dictionary keys and **"values"** contains the keys as well as the values for the dictionary.
- output{} is the dictionary that I am aiming to get as an output.

I implemented the following code

```
list4 = []

for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(len(Keys[1:])):
        if Keys[j]==values[i]:
            for k in range(i,len(values)):                
                list4.append(values[k])
                if Keys[j+1] == values[k]:
                    del list4[-1]
                    break

                        
            output = dict(zip(Keys[j], list4))
            print(output)
```

This logic is not working, is there any implementation for this?

Comment: this is not valid in python `{a:'a1','a2'}`

Comment: What's with the three different names (Keys vs keys vs Key, values vs Values vs value)?

Comment: Did you mean: `output = [ {'a':['a1','a2']}, ... ]`?

Comment: Yeah the output is output = [ {'a':['a1','a2']}, ... ], the one in the post is a typo

Comment: or did you mean: `output = [ {'a':'a1,a2'}, ... ]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could scan `values` and create a new list when you find an element from `Keys`:

```
d = {}
output = {Keys[0]: d}
lst = None
for val in values():
    if val in Keys:
        lst = []
        d[val] = lst
    elif lst is not None:
        lst.append(val)
```

It gives as expected:

```
{'a': {'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
       'b': ['b4', 'b5'],
       'c': ['c4', 'c3'],
       'd': ['d4', 'd6'],
       'e': ['e4', 'e3']}}
```

Comment: I edited my question a bit, your answers work for the previous question! Thanks, but could you again see the question and suggest an answer?

Comment: yeah maybe now you can see the edit, I changed the output dict to output= {'a':{'a':['a1','a2'],'b':['b4','b5'],'c':['c4','c3'],'d':['d4','d6'],'e':['e4','e3']}}

Comment: @RishabhGaur: You should better explain what you want. I assume the first element of Keys to have a special role, but why was `c2` discarded? Because you want exactly 2 elements, or want all lists to have same number of elements, hence the shorter one.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I didn't even notice `c2` is discarded. Completely agree with you.

Comment: @SergeBallesta  Pardon that was a typo too, The mismatch between the output dictionaries and input list has been rectified. Ignore that C2,

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
Keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = ['a', 'a1', 'a2', 'b', 'b4', 'b5', 'c', 'c4', 'c3',
          'c2', 'd', 'd4', 'd6', 'e', 'e4', 'e3']

di = {}
for k, g in groupby(values, key=lambda i: i[0]):
    di[k] = list(g)[1:]

# or with dict comprehension
# di = {k:list(g)[1:] for k, g in groupby(values, key=lambda i: i[0])}
print(di)
```

```
{'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
 'b': ['b4', 'b5'],
 'c': ['c4', 'c3', 'c2'],
 'd': ['d4', 'd6'],
 'e': ['e4', 'e3']}
```

Comment: I edited my question a bit, your answers work for the previous question! Thanks, but could you again see the question and suggest an answer?

Comment: Change `list(g)[1:]` with  `", ".join(list(g)[1:])`? Is this what you are looking for? The question has changed a lot. Can you please post the **exact** output you want to achieve?

Comment: nope not working, the output is coming as follows {'a': 'a1, a2', 'b': 'b4, b5', 'c': 'c4, c3, c2', 'd': 'd4, d6', 'e': 'e4, e3'}

Comment: Basically, the example output in your question is not syntactically correct. So I can only *guess* what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can check now, It was a typo, sorry, and thanks for helping out

Comment: OK, so you want whole result to be associated with a key `"a"` in a new dictionary: `new_di = {"a": di}` should do it.